# Telnet: 'Connection Refused' when I run python script on localhost

Tags: python, unix, terminal, localhost, telnet

I am attempting to run a python script on a localhost server in order to interact with this script from other terminal windows.

I know there is no fault in the python script as this exact method of connection works on a different machine.

First, I run the following in Terminal Window 1: `python ./myserver.py localhost 8080` - my script gives me a message saying that the server script has successfully started.

Second, using Terminal Window 2 I attempt to connect to this localhost via Telnet using the following: `telnet localhost 8080` - this is where my error lies. Immediately after I enter the command I receive the following message,

```
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

How can I fix or at least troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: We're going to have to see your code.

Comment: @jwodder are you sure? Just it works on another machine and my script only takes the ip address and port given to it as arguments - i.e. 'localhost', '8080'

Comment: Try with below command first - 
`netstat -A inet -ea|grep  telnets` to see the listener port for telnet and then change the port number while using telnet..

Comment: This returns nothing. I assume that means that the port is never active? When I remove the grep telnets I cannot see any localhost active with the port I mention.

Comment: @JoelBiffin - It means telnet is not running, you need to start the service -

`/etc/init.d/xinetd - restart`

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR do you have any idea what the path to xinetd would be on a mac machine?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to VIPIN KUMAR for this suggestion.

I needed to restart the xinetd service as the telnet service was not running correctly.